# Tiger DVD ripper

Tags: dvd, powerbook

I have an old PowerBook G4. Since my new Mac hasn't any built-in DVD reader, I would like to use the old one to copy the movies onto a USB stick to be able to watch them when I'm traveling with the new Mac (and then delete them, I don't want to do anything illegal! [In my country copying DVDs for personal use is legal.]).

Sometimes I can simply copy the DVD folder content, but that obviously doesn't work with encrypted DVDs. What is the best free DVD ripper for a Mac running OS X Tiger?

Comment: P.S. I'm new to this stack excange site and I didn't found an appropriate tag

Comment: Software recommendations are generally off topic (see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)) and such question are typically closed. Did you try searching with Google?

Comment: Yes, of course I googled it, but most sites where I could find pieces of information about this kind of software for older os x versions are owned by a company that sells one of them, so they're all very partial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handbreak is a great software for ripping DVDs on a Mac. Since your device is older, you won't find a download on the official site, but there are archived versions [here](http://www.oldapps.com/mac/handbrake.php). You will should be able the right download for your computer. If you can't find it, try [this](http://www.oldapps.com/mac/handbrake.php?old_handbrake=18) download.

You can **get an official Apple disc drive** called the [Apple USB Super Drive](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD564LL/A/apple-usb-superdrive).(it is a bit pricy, $79 USD). You can also find some pretty cheap USB drives for your new Mac, then use Handbreak. [Official Handbreak link(Mac OS X 10.6 or later)](https://handbrake.fr)

**Edit:**

You will have to install libdvdcss in order to rip copyrighted discs. It's pretty easily to install, just Google it.

Comment: Unless things have changed, HandBreak cannot by itself transcode commercial DVD's as it does not have the capability to remove the CSS Encryption. You'd have to install libdvdcss or any other 3rd party software for this function in order for HandBreak to work on copy protected discs.